# How do we reconcile the following two statements about primes?

Tags: number-theory

1-arbitrarily large gaps can occur between consecutive primes.
2-Legendre conjecture ( and similar conjectures like Bertrand's postulate ) which states that there is a prime number between n^2 and (n + 1)^2.

Can these two statements be both true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following :

$$(n+1)^2-n^2=2n+1\text{ can be arbitrarily large.}$$

Comment: thanks, so simple it's embarrassing.